# Using AVFoundation, how to remove middle 400pixels from all frames of a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I am looking for a way to slice the middle part of the video and remove it , and merge the other two parts and render a new track. Is there any way in AVFoundation to perform this?

For eg:- please see the below illustration, if the full video height is from 1 to 4, I need to crop a slice from 2 to 3 and combine that [1-2] and [3-4] parts into a new video track. (Following is an illustration of ONE frame not the whole clip)

1----------------------------------

2----------------------------------

3----------------------------------

4----------------------------------

Comment: Do you want to crop the video to specified height and width? Like a frame made of CGRect(0,30,100,100).. ?

Comment: Yes I want to crop a frame like CGRect(0,30,100,50) and remove it, and combine the left over parts. Is this even possible dirrectly? or Do I have to do frame based editing?

Comment: You can use AVFoundation framework for this. Using Layering in AVFoundation, It is possible to specify a frame of a video to crop and then you can export it. But exporting takes time.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can see its possible to crop a Rect area and export it. But what I want is not to crop and export, but to combine two live video feeds ( split by cropping the original video) and combine those parts on the fly. As far as I can see there's no way to do this without doing it frame by frame and render those frame in to a video. I'm wondering is there an easy way to do this without going for that approach.

Comment: you will need to make AVMutableVideoComposition, its easily doable but it takes many lines of code

Comment: Make an AVMutableVideoComposition and Layer instructions in it. You can use layer instructions to merge two videos side by side and then you can directly play using AVPlayer. But for saving the video, you have to export it. But AVPlayer is very useful to show the preview to the user. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I will try this. Many thanks! Anyways do you know a good place to look for instructions on how to use Layer instructions etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try to overlay a cropped video in the middle of your background video instead of trying to "make a whole".

Take a look at [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)'s [blend filters](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#blending-modes) and then use a [movie writer](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#filtering-live-video).